# Calculating the Fourier coefficients of a vector valued function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Putting convergence issues aside for the moment, for a periodic function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ its Fourier series is defined as
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \langle f, x_k\rangle x_k(x) \tag{1}$$
where $\{x_k(x)\}$ is an orthonormal basis.

I am looking for an extension of the above to vector valued functions. For example, suppose $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f$ is periodic. Then there we can similarly decompose $f$ into a Fourier series:
$$f = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \textbf{a}_k \textbf{x}_k(x) \tag{2}$$
where $\{\textbf{x}_k(x)\}$ is an orthonormal basis.

In the real-valued case the coefficients $a_k$ are scalars and given by an inner product as in (1). Is there an explicit formula for computing the Fourier coefficients $\textbf{a}_k$ for vector valued functions such as (2)? The obvious choice is to do things component wise. That is, since $\textbf{a}_k$ and $\textbf{x}_k(x)$ both have $n$ components, then
$$(\textbf{a}_k)_i = \langle f_i, (\textbf{x}_k)_i \rangle, \quad i = 1, \ldots n$$
but I could not find any such formula in any textbooks. Is this the right expression for $a_k$?

Comment: The $a_k$’s should still be complex numbers, not vector-valued. Fourier coefficients are a concept for Hilbert-space theory and simply mean “components relative to a given orthonormal basis”; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4719125/568204) for more details. Now, just apply all of that to the Hilbert space $H=L^2(X;\Bbb{R}^n)$, where you can actually replace the target $\Bbb{R}^n$ by another Hilbert space if you like (once you develop the proper integration theory).

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think I noticed a typo which might explain things. The sum in (2) should be taken over $\mathbb{Z}^n$ not just $\mathbb{Z}$. In this case would the coefficients still be in $\mathbb{C}$ and not $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for that link. Going off that example, if we take $H = L^2(X; \mathbb{R}^n)$ then a basis is given by $x_k(x) = \exp{(2\pi i k \cdot x)}$ where $x \in \mathbb{Z}^n$. This is a scalar, so wouldn't $a_k$ have to be a vector?

Comment: Coefficients still in $\Bbb{C}$, yes. Btw, I have a typo, it should be $H=L^2(X;\Bbb{C}^n)$ given the context (Fourier series usually involves complex numbers…). Next, is the function defined by $x_k(x)=\exp(2\pi i k\cdot x)$ an element of $L^2(X;\Bbb{C}^n)$ or $L^2(X;\Bbb{C})\equiv L^2(X)$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo I originally thought the function $x_k(x)$ belongs to $L^2(X)$, but now I am having some doubts as they wouldn't form a basis for $L^2(X; \mathbb{C}^n)$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo To explain it better, in the book *The Three-Dimensional Navier-Stokes Equations* by Robinson, Rodrigo, and Sadowski they say "For real-valued functions defined on $\mathbb{T}^3$ it is often useful to consider their Fourier expansion $u(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^3} \hat{u}_k \exp(ik \cdot x)$ where the coefficients $\hat{u}_k$ are complex numbers...When $u$ is an $m$-component vector-valued function the coefficients $\hat{u}_k$ are elements of $\mathbb{C}^m$".

Comment: yes, they belong to $L^2(X)$. So, how can they belong to $L^2(X;\Bbb{C}^n)$, and furthermore how can they form a basis?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Based on the quote that I shared, do $L^2(X, \mathbb{C}$ and $L^2(X, \mathbb{C}^n)$ share a common basis (with the difference being that in this basis, an element in one space has different sized Fourier coefficients than the other)?

Comment: I see what they mean; it’s actually essentially equivalent to what I wrote. I was objecting mainly because you wrote a product of vectors in (2), and that’s wrong/meaningless. What they’re saying is for each component function of $u$, do the usual Fourier series, and then stick those resulting Fourier series into a column vector. What I was suggesting is that given the ON basis of $L^2(X)$ generated by $\phi_k(x)=\exp(ik\cdot x)$, consider the ON basis of $L^2(X;\Bbb{C}^n)$ generated by $\Phi_{k,a}(x)=(0,\cdots, \phi_k(x),\cdots, 0)$, with $\phi_k$ in $a^{th}$ slot. The net result is the same.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you, that is very helpful. So if I have understood correctly, we carry out the Fourier expansion (what I have as (1) in my original post) for each component of $f$ individually?

Comment: yes that’s right.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you again for all your help!